# change sibling element's style in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Any thoughts why after clicking the first div here the next element in line on the same level (a sibling?) is not changing its style as instructed below in javascript? the display: none should disappear at style after clicking on the first element.
thanks in advance

```html
<div id="y" style="width: 75%; left: 146px; onclick=" function1() "; ">
  par1
</div>
<ul id="x" style="width: 75%; left: 146px; display: none;">
  par2
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function function1() {
    event.srcElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = "";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have missed a double quote, so the `onclick` attribute is not being interpreted correctly. Secondly, once that's fixed, you should set `display` to `block`, not an empty string, to make the element visible. Try this:

```html
<div id="y" style="width: 75%; left: 146px;" onclick="function1()">
  par1
</div>
<ul id="x" style="width: 75%; left: 146px; display: none;">
  par2
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
  function function1() {
    console.log(event);
    event.srcElement.nextElementSibling.style.display = "block";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you have syntax errors, here's the fix:

```
<div id="y" style="width: 75%; left: 146px;" onclick="function1();">
```

You were missing clossing quotes from your style property and an extra quote in your onclick property